# How to use function present in one file in another file in watir ruby

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, function, watir

I am new to Ruby and need help in accessing a function which is present in another file. The scenario is I have 2 files  lets say test.rb and functions.rb

in test.rb i have the below code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'win32ole'
require 'erb' 
require 'ostruct' 
require 'C:\functions'
include Watir
U_RL="some url"
browser
if
ie.text.include?"There is a problem with this website's security certificate."
then
ie.link(:id, 'overridelink').click
end
```

now in the functions.rb file I have the below code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'win32ole'

include Watir

def browser
      ie=IE.new 
      ie.maximize
      ie.goto U_RL
      ie.focus
      ie.bring_to_front
      ie.wait()
end
```

When I run test.rb, I get the error "Undefined local variable or method 'ie' for main:object

I can see that the browser is opened and even the the mentioned url is coming up, but when the security warning page comes up it is not clicking on ie.link(:id, 'overridelink').click.

Please let me know how to over come this

Comment: Please, format your code (you can get this by indenting your code in the editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition of the `browser` method, the scope of `ie` is local to that method. It can not be accessed outside of it.

This code needs to be completely refactored, but for now, you could just have `browser` return the local instance of `ie`, and set it in test.rb

functions.rb:

```
def browser
      ie=IE.new 
      ie.maximize
      ie.goto U_RL
      ie.focus
      ie.bring_to_front
      ie.wait()
      ie # last value is returned in ruby; can be explicit and do `return ie` as well
end
```

test.rb:

```
ie = browser
if ie.text.include?"There is a problem with this website's security certificate."
then
  ie.link(:id, 'overridelink').click
end
```

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned above but I still get the same message "Undefined local variable or method 'ie' for main:object " Please suggest if any thing has to be changed in code

Comment: Hi.. I am sorry, i was not doing it right. I have checked it again and it works. thanks for the solution. Please let me know if you know have any better or efficient way of doing this. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You should require second file. Like this

```
require_relative 'functions'
```